# Prove that if $\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for which $a_m=0\implies a_1$ or $a_2=0.$

Tags: polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Define a sequence of integers $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ such that $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1}=f(a_n).$ Prove that if $\exists m\ne 0$ such that $a_m=0\implies a_1$ or $a_2=0.$

---

$$
f(x)=b_l x^2+b_{l-1} x^{l-1}+\cdots+b_1 x+b_0
$$
If $a_1=b_0=0,$ then $a_n=0\;\forall n \geqslant 2.$
Now, say $\exists m$ such that $a_m=0.$

We see
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_n=\;
b_l&\left[a_n^l-a_{n-1}^l\right]+\\
b_{l-1}&\left[a_n^{l-1}-a_{n-1}^{l-1}\right]+\cdots+\\
b_1&\left[a_n-a_{n-1}\right].
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
a_2-a_1 &\mid a_3-a_2 \\
a_3-a_2 &\mid a_4-a_3 \\
&\,\vdots \\
a_m-a_{m-1} &\mid a_{m+1}-a_m \\
\implies a_2-a_1 &\mid a_{m+1}-a_m \\
\implies a_2-b_0 &\mid a_{m+1}\left[\because a_m=0, a_1=b_0\right] \\
a_{m+1}=f\left(a_m\right)\;&\!=f(0)=b_0 \\
a_2-b_0 &\mid b_0 \\
b_0 &\mid a_2.
\end{align}
I feel like I'm close to solving it, but I have to show $a_2=0$ somehow. Can someone please provide a possible continuation to my solution?

Comment: What can you say about the sequence $a_{n+1}-a_n$? You already know $a_{m+1}-a_m=a_1-a_0$, which might be helpful.

Comment: @radekzak I have gotten $a_n-a_{n-1} \mid a_{n+1}-a_n$, but what other than that? Also $a_1 \mid a_{n+1}-a_n$

Comment: If you look at $a_{n+1}-a_n$ as a sequence of integers, what properties will it have?

Comment: @radekzak I'm not totally sure about this but is that sequence going to be periodic other than the fact that $b_0$ divides every number in that sequence.

Comment: Any idea on this problem anyone??

Answer (score 1):

Let us put $c_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$. Then, as you've observed, $c_n \mid c_{n+1}$. At the same time, as you've also observed, $c_m=c_0$, and actually since $a_{m+t}=a_t$ for any $t$, sequence $c_n$ is also periodic with period $m$.

Therefore $|c_0| \leqslant |c_1| \leqslant \ldots \leqslant |c_m|=|c_0|$, so actually we have equality everywhere, and $c_n = \pm c_0$ for any $n$.

If $c_1=-c_0$, then $a_2-a_1=a_0-a_1$, so $a_2=0$. Suppose $c_1=c_0$. If all $c_n$ are equal, then $a_n$ is an arithmetic sequence. But $a_0=a_m=0$, so it has to be identically zero in this case.

If they are not all equal, then at some point we have $c_n=-c_{n+1}$. But this means $a_{n+1}-a_n = a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}$, so $a_n = a_{n+2}$. This situation can be ruled out easily (it means $a_{n+t}$ is periodic with period $2$, so $m \mid 2$), hence we are done.